# Sync Azure AD users to SQL Server on vm or Sql Database Users Table

Tags: azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-sql-server

How can we synchronize Azure AD users with a user table in the database?

Answer (score 0):

To Sync Azure AD users to SQL make sure each property stored in the data source maps properly to an AD user's attribute.

This [article](https://4sysops.com/archives/sync-active-directory-users-with-a-sql-database/) by Adam Bertram has code and whole process to Sync Azure AD users to Sql Database.

As per official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/authentication-aad-configure?tabs=azure-powershell)
**Azure role-based access control (Azure RBAC) applies only to the portal and is not propagated to SQL Server.**

> **Note**
>
> Database users (with the exception of administrators) cannot be
> created using the Azure portal. Azure roles are not propagated to the
> database in SQL Database, the SQL Managed Instance, or Azure Synapse.
> Azure roles are used for managing Azure Resources, and do not apply to
> database permissions. For example, the SQL Server Contributor role
> does not grant access to connect to the database in SQL Database, the
> SQL Managed Instance, or Azure Synapse. The access permission must be
> granted directly in the database using Transact-SQL statements.